# iPad popover not resizing properly after search keyboard is dismissed

Tags: ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller

I have a popover that contains a tableview (which is inside a navigation controller) with custom cells and a search bar in the header. Once I enter the search bar the popover shrinks appropriately to make room for the keyboard. Good so far. Once I dismiss the keyboard either by pressing the search button or the dismiss keyboard button, the popover appears to resize a little but does not does return to the full length as I would expect. I've tried all the suggestions to update the popoversize and contentsizeinpopover. They seem to have no effect.

Any thoughts or workarounds?

Thanks,

Rob

Comment: "I've tried all the suggestions to update the popoversize and contentsizeinpopover." – What are these suggestions? Please show us what you have tried (incl. code).

Comment: I've seen the same issue, it started happening around 4.3 and happens in apple apps too. I think there is an ios bug but I haven't tried 4.3.3 yet